# How to keep users from accessing webpage by changing url

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux

Using an api that was already created, when a user comes upon the login page they can choose to login or just edit the url from the localhost 3000 to /dashboard and it does not redirect back to the login page. It should only be accessible to the user when a username and password are provided. Tried changing the code multiple times and even the privateroutes but still cannot seem to get it to not allow you to access the page. Restarted back over with the previous code in an attempt to figure it out even though im sure im looking at the answer

Its a mix of the Login.js and then towards the end its the PrivateRoute.js

```
import axiosWithAuth from '../data/axiosWithAuth';
const Login = props => {


const [loginCreds, setLoginCreds] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
    err: null
  });

  const handleChange = e => {

    setLoginCreds({

      ...loginCreds,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      err: null
    });
  };

  const login = () => {
    const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const url = "https://pintreachbackend.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login";
    axiosWithAuth()
      .post(proxy +url , {
        username: loginCreds.username,
        password: loginCreds.password
      })
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
        props.history.push("/dashboard");
        console.log(login)
      })
      .catch(err =>
        setLoginCreds({
          ...loginCreds,
          err: "Error logging in. Please try again."
        })
      );
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginCreds.username === "" || loginCreds.password === ""
      ? setLoginCreds({
          ...loginCreds,
          err: "Please complete all login fields."
        })
      : login();
  };
  return (
    <div className="login-page">
    <form>
        <h4>Enter Login Creds</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Enter username..."
          value={loginCreds.username}
          onChange={handleChange}
          autoComplete="username"
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Enter password..."
          value={loginCreds.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Login</button>
        {loginCreds.err && (
          <div className="error-container">{loginCreds.err}</div>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;  ~~~    










This is the PrivateRoute.js

    ~~~import React from "react";
    import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
    import axiosWithAuth from "../data/axiosWithAuth";

    /*
    Private Route rules:
    1. It has the same API as <Route />.
    2. It renders a <Route /> and passes all the props through to it.
    3. It checks if the user is authenticated, if they are, it renders the 
    “component” prop. If not, it redirects the user to /login.
    */
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    // const Component = props.component

    return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        axiosWithAuth ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } 
    }} 
    />
        )
       }
      />
     )
    }

    export default PrivateRoute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace BrowserRouter to  MemoryRouter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use state to detect whether the user is authenticated or not, if not then redirect.
For example

```
this.state={
    loggedIn:false
}
render(){
    if(!this.state.loggedIn)
        return <Redirect to='/loginPage'>
    return <div>Is Logged in</div>
}
```

For more information you can google `React router guard`

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the React.Context API which is there to assist these kind of scenarios.

At the bootstrap of your application, you can set the default context and then you can pass the context to the respective components by consuming that context in the component to decide whether to render the component or redirect the user to home page.

For more information [see](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)